# Are there functors from ordinary categories into multicategories?

Tags: category-theory

I'm asking because then the tensor product would be a universal arrow from $M \times N$ in the multicategory **R-Mod**_mult to an "embedding functor" from **R-Mod** into **R-Mod**_mult.

Comment: You can view a category as a multicategory with only 1 to 1 arrows.

Comment: @DmitryVaintrob Ah, sorry.